# How to zoom toward a 3D mesh with qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm using a Wheelevent to Zoom in/out in a `QWidget` view,in use the event to translate the `QCamera`, is there a solution from the qt api  to move toward a point or zoom with the camera to a specific point? I searched in many sections but did'nt find something useful unfortunately.

Comment: Please rewrite your question. What you wrote is rather confusing and it is not entirely clear what you are asking. What do you mean by zoom in/out a QWidget? Do you enlarge the widget? Do you only want to zoom in the 3D scene? If you want to set the camera's position you can do so using setPosition() and adjust the view center and up vector. But your title sounds like you want to view an entity. There are functions in `QCamera` called viewEntity(), viewSphere() and viewAll() but they are only available from Qt 5.10 and up. Please specify what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am really sorry for my bad explanation, I want to zoom in the 3D scene actually, I have a 3D mesh in the (0,0,0) position and I want to zoom toward it with the mouse wheel. sorry again for my bad explanation.

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it :D You want to move the camera long the line that goes from the camera center to (0, 0, 0), right? I'm not sure if there is any functionality in Qt3D already, but I guess the easiest solution would be to simply calculate the vector from camera center to (0, 0, 0), i.e. this is simply the camera position itself (if view center is somewhere else, you have to subtract the two 3D vectors). Normalize that vector and then multiply it by a zoom factor (try out what is a good value) and add it to the camera position.

Comment: @FlorianBlume Hi there, **How to use** `viewSphere` method in .qml file, for as order the doc said  [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-camera.html#viewSphere-method)

Comment: Hey, if you have a question post one. Comments are for clarification mostly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Stefan Reinhardt suggested to use `QAbstractCameraController` to achieve what you want to do. The example I provided is a quick-and-dirty solution. I agree that using the camera controller is the way intended in Qt3D.

---

The Qt3D API doesn't support this directly, but you can implement it easily yourself.

Here is a minimally working example, that should get you started (note, that you have to adjust the upvector, when scrolling past the view center I guess):

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "graphicswindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    GraphicsWindow graphicsWindow;
    graphicsWindow.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

`graphicswindow.h`:

```
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>
#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>

class GraphicsWindow : public Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow {
public:
    GraphicsWindow();
    void wheelEvent ( QWheelEvent * event ) override;

private:
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene();
};
```

`graphicswindow.cpp`:

```
#include "graphicswindow.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QVector3D>
#include <Qt3DRender/QCamera>
#include <Qt3DRender/QMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QGoochMaterial>
#include <Qt3DExtras/QCuboidMesh>

GraphicsWindow::GraphicsWindow() : Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow() {
    // You could also create a dedicated setup method
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *root = createScene();
    setRootEntity(root);
    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = this->camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(20.0, 20.0, 20.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));
}

void GraphicsWindow::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) {
    QVector3D camPos = this->camera()->position();
    camPos.normalize();
    camPos = this->camera()->position() - QVector3D(event->delta() / 300.f,
                                                event->delta() / 300.f,
                                                event->delta() / 300.f);
    this->camera()->setPosition(camPos);
}


Qt3DCore::QEntity* GraphicsWindow::createScene() {
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    Qt3DRender::QMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QGoochMaterial(rootEntity);

    //Cube
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *cubeEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh *cubeMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh;

    cubeEntity->addComponent(cubeMesh);
    cubeEntity->addComponent(material);

    return rootEntity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Florian,i was folowing your previous comment and i made a smiliar code , it's working good,the only problem that i'm having is that when i scroll it returns the the camera initial position of the camera then does the zoom.

Comment: You could probably also use the Qt3D input classes from here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3dinput-module.html. But to me it seems that this is more suitable if you are making e.g. a game. For a quick prototype I'd use the code I posted above.

Comment: Thank you Florian,your advices were so helpful for me,i'll try to folow what you said and keep you updated.

Comment: When using Qt3D (and v 5.10+) i would recommend to use the [QAbstractCameraController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qabstractcameracontroller.html) to implement 3D Camera Movement. There are already two (imho not very intuitive/userfriendly) ready to use implementations of the camera controler [QFirstPersonCameraController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qfirstpersoncameracontroller.html) and [QOrbitCameraController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dextras-qorbitcameracontroller.html).

Comment: just a little edit to my comment as the qt docs are wrong here: Instead of implementing `frameActionTriggered()` you need to implement `moveCamera()` as i just saw in the source code (e.g. [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/extras/defaults/qfirstpersoncameracontroller.cpp))